# What can cause 0xc0000409 in ntdll.dll when building for /subsystem:windows on machines without Visual Studio installed?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, crash

My application crashes with exception 0xc0000409 in ntdll.dll (all according to Windows event viewer) immediately at startup on machines which doesn't have Visual Studio installed. On machines with Visual Studio installed everything works fine. The crash only happens when building with /subsystem:windows. With /subsystem:console everything works fine.

More info: I'm using CMAKE and qt_add_executable(AppName WIN32 ${PROJECT_SOURCES}) for building with /subsystem:windows and qt_add_executable(AppName ${PROJECT_SOURCES}) for building with /subsystem:console.

Any idea of how to find the root cause? I cannot debug since the error isn't reproducible with Visual Studio installed.

Comment: Find the C++ option to use the CRT statically, not dll.

Comment: You can still install a debugger without Visual Studio, i.e. WinDbg. With that little info, we can't really help you. A stack trace would probably give the problem away.

Comment: @MichaelChourdakis According to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/md-mt-ld-use-run-time-library?view=msvc-160 it seems like the CRT is always statically, or do I miss something?

Comment: The `ntdll.dll` is not part of the CRT (more likely part of the WinAPI and system library). You can't statically link to the stuff in there and will most likely need to install the appropriate VC Redistributable on the target machine(s). See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57891487/10871073), for example.

Comment: @AdrianMole The appropriate VC Redistributable is installed on the machine for which it crashes.

Comment: The ntdll.dll is now included with the Windows SDK. (previously known as Platfrom SDK)
`C:\Windows\SysWOW64 [64 bit version]`
`C:\Windows\System32 [32 bit version]`
This might be caused due to the files missing. I suggest you could try to initiate SFC scan and check if it helps.
Please refer to the below article to initiate SFC scan and know more about it:
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/929833

Comment: @Jeaninez-MSFT It wouldn't crash within ntdll.dll if it was missing. The file is fine.

Comment: @JonathanS. Nice idea. I tried. Unfortunately I didn't get good info because the debug info is garbage due to that the copy protection system we apply (wibu) modifies the exe after compilation. But then I tried without copy protection and everything works fine. So it seems like the error is in the copy protection by wibu.